# Tamed dogs and cats won't leave me alone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft SMP

I've tamed a couple dozen wolves and cats, brought them back to my home, bred them, and left them in a kennel. My plan was to position the cats around my house to keep away creepers, and take a couple dogs with me when I go adventuring. The rest have been made to sit.

My problem is that while I'm out and about for an hour or two, out of nowhere my animals will all warp to my position, regardless of how near or far I am from my home where they were told to sit. Having 50 animals warp to your position in a 2x1 mining tunnel is not a good time.

Is there anything I can do to keep my animals from warping to me all the time or am I going to have to do something monstrous?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kill them.  Kill them all.

That is your only solution without a mod I believe

Sadly, I'm being serious.  I have same issue.  That's been my only solution so far without modding.

Comment: It's funny because it's true. After the novelty of wolves wore off, I realized how useless and annoying they were. I didn't even bother with cats this time around. Good luck.

Comment: I had the same problem and settled on the same solution...

Comment: I'm just waiting for PETA to show up to shout about Minecraft being designed specifically as an 'animal murder simulator'

Comment: @JakeKing, cats aren't useless -you *do* know that cats repel creepers, right? :) That alone is worth a few of them sitting around, guarding my sandstone Egyptian temple (plus the ancient Egyptians are said to worship cats).

Comment: @Cyclops True, but I find that it's usually more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Can't you just make them sit? Isn't that supposed to make them stationary?

Comment: That got dark fast

Answer (score 5):

Dogs, if made to sit, will stay sitting down without following you, unless you start being attacked. When you are attacked, your dogs will automatically come to your rescue, even though you probably don't need it. I find that it doesn't really bother me, but if it bothers you, you should probably kill them all. :(

Comment: You may be right, but I don't think this really is a symptom of normal wolf behaviour. Having also had this issue I can confirm that the wolves (and cats) will appear when I have not been attacked.

Comment: Also, sitting dogs only come to your aid when you are nearby. If you are far enough away from them that (if standing) they would need to teleport to you (roughly a 20 x 20 x 10 block area), they no longer respond to you getting attacked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so certain about that. Playing SMP. At least twice when I was the only player on the server at the time I've had all my wolves or all my cats teleport to me.  Also, while working parallel with another player on the server, his wolves spawned to him.  He also experiences the issue while alone.  Though possibly a chunk loading error, since the both of us have 'sitting-animals-spawned-to-me' errors while being the only player online, I find it unlikely that the issue stems from a player other than the pets' owner interacting with the populated chunk.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the above spoken they will sit and stay there until you tell them to follow. they will not teleport when they have been told to sit. You dont need to kill them.
I beleave in an update this bug was fixed because i do not have this problem unless i am running and my wolf has not been told to sit down.

Comment: That may be the intended behaviour, but as I did my best to make it clear in my question - it's not what happens. Not in SMP anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know what is causing this. It happens if the chunk the pet is in is not loaded, and another player enters the area causing the chunk to load.

Comment: Is this confirmed by anything, or just speculative? If it's confirmed, it's definitely worth some points (and a message to Jeb)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.. I have a bunch of cats in a massive 'cat room'. I leave the game after making sure they are all sitting. when I reenter the game then most of them appear next to me and I have to take them all back to their room (which is a very tedious mission). The only way to avoid this is to log in using a different user name. The down side is that the cats no longer see me as their owner. So if I want to take a cat with me for whatever reason I will go into my cat room, exit the game, and reenter with the user name that I used while taming the cats. Then I make all of them sit except for one or two.

Still looking for a better, less tedious solution though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP doesn't have another account.

Answer (score -1):

Put a piece of fence and use a lead and tie them to it you don't even have to make them sit.